# Erlang Tracing - How to ignore messages to erlang processes

Tags: erlang, trace

I have an application which is tracing a process for [send, 'receive'].  However, the application is receiving trace message that the traced process is exchanging messages with the process `code_server` with messages such as `{code_server,{module,random}}`.

Is there any way of filtering out these messages from and to "system processes"?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own event handler and added to error_logger event manager. In the event handle function to filter your message.

Two files copied from couchdb open source project for example, couch_log.erl, couch_event_sup.erl

```
couch_event_sup.erl
```

% Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
% use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
% the License at
%
%   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
%
% Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
% distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
% WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
% License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
% the License.

-module(couch_log).
-behaviour(gen_event).

-export([start_link/0,stop/0]).
-export([debug/2, info/2, error/2]).
-export([debug_on/0,info_on/0,get_level/0,get_level_integer/0, set_level/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_event/2, terminate/2, code_change/3, handle_info/2, handle_call/2]).
-export([read/2]).

-define(LEVEL_ERROR, 3).
-define(LEVEL_INFO, 2).
-define(LEVEL_DEBUG, 1).
-define(LEVEL_TMI, 0).

debug(Format, Args) ->
    {ConsoleMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(self(), debug, Format, Args),
    gen_event:sync_notify(error_logger, {couch_debug, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg}).

info(Format, Args) ->
    {ConsoleMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(self(), info, Format, Args),
    gen_event:sync_notify(error_logger, {couch_info, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg}).

error(Format, Args) ->
    {ConsoleMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(self(), error, Format, Args),
    gen_event:sync_notify(error_logger, {couch_error, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg}).


level_integer(error)    -> ?LEVEL_ERROR;
level_integer(info)     -> ?LEVEL_INFO;
level_integer(debug)    -> ?LEVEL_DEBUG;
level_integer(tmi)      -> ?LEVEL_TMI;
level_integer(_Else)    -> ?LEVEL_ERROR. % anything else default to ERROR level

level_atom(?LEVEL_ERROR) -> error;
level_atom(?LEVEL_INFO) -> info;
level_atom(?LEVEL_DEBUG) -> debug;
level_atom(?LEVEL_TMI) -> tmi.


start_link() ->
    couch_event_sup:start_link({local, couch_log}, error_logger, couch_log, []).

stop() ->
    couch_event_sup:stop(couch_log).

init([]) ->
    % read config and register for configuration changes

    % just stop if one of the config settings change. couch_server_sup
    % will restart us and then we will pick up the new settings.
    ok = couch_config:register(
        fun("log", "file") ->
            ?MODULE:stop();
        ("log", "level") ->
            ?MODULE:stop();
        ("log", "include_sasl") ->
            ?MODULE:stop()
        end),

    Filename = couch_config:get("log", "file", "couchdb.log"),
    Level = level_integer(list_to_atom(couch_config:get("log", "level", "info"))),
    Sasl = list_to_atom(couch_config:get("log", "include_sasl", "true")),

    case ets:info(?MODULE) of
    undefined -> ets:new(?MODULE, [named_table]);
    _ -> ok
    end,
    ets:insert(?MODULE, {level, Level}),

    case file:open(Filename, [append]) of
    {ok, Fd} ->
        {ok, {Fd, Level, Sasl}};
    {error, eacces} ->
        {stop, {file_permission_error, Filename}};
    Error ->
        {stop, Error}
    end.

debug_on() ->
    get_level_integer() =< ?LEVEL_DEBUG.

info_on() ->
    get_level_integer() =< ?LEVEL_INFO.

set_level(LevelAtom) ->
    set_level_integer(level_integer(LevelAtom)).

get_level() ->
    level_atom(get_level_integer()).

get_level_integer() ->
    try
        ets:lookup_element(?MODULE, level, 2)
    catch error:badarg ->
        ?LEVEL_ERROR
    end.

set_level_integer(Int) ->
    gen_event:call(error_logger, couch_log, {set_level_integer, Int}).

handle_event({couch_error, ConMsg, FileMsg}, {Fd, _LogLevel, _Sasl}=State) ->
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({couch_info, ConMsg, FileMsg}, {Fd, LogLevel, _Sasl}=State)
when LogLevel =< ?LEVEL_INFO ->
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({couch_debug, ConMsg, FileMsg}, {Fd, LogLevel, _Sasl}=State)
when LogLevel =< ?LEVEL_DEBUG ->
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({error_report, _, {Pid, _, _}}=Event, {Fd, _LogLevel, Sasl}=State)
when Sasl =/= false ->
    {ConMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(Pid, error, "~p", [Event]),
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({error, _, {Pid, Format, Args}}, {Fd, _LogLevel, Sasl}=State)
when Sasl =/= false ->
    {ConMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(Pid, error, Format, Args),
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({_, _, {Pid, _, _}}=Event, {Fd, LogLevel, _Sasl}=State)
when LogLevel =< ?LEVEL_TMI ->
    % log every remaining event if tmi!
    log(Fd, Pid, tmi, "~p", [Event]),
    {ok, State};
handle_event(_Event, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

handle_call({set_level_integer, NewLevel}, {Fd, _LogLevel, Sasl}) ->
    ets:insert(?MODULE, {level, NewLevel}),
    {ok, ok, {Fd, NewLevel, Sasl}}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

terminate(_Arg, {Fd, _LoggingLevel, _Sasl}) ->
    file:close(Fd).

log(Fd, Pid, Level, Format, Args) ->
    Msg = io_lib:format(Format, Args),
    ok = io:format("[~s] [~p] ~s~n", [Level, Pid, Msg]), % dump to console too
    Msg2 = re:replace(lists:flatten(Msg),"\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "\r\n",
        [global, {return, list}]),
    ok = io:format(Fd, "[~s] [~s] [~p] ~s\r~n", [httpd_util:rfc1123_date(), Level, Pid, Msg2]).

log(Fd, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg) ->
    ok = io:put_chars(ConsoleMsg),
    ok = io:put_chars(Fd, FileMsg).

get_log_messages(Pid, Level, Format, Args) ->
    ConsoleMsg = unicode:characters_to_binary(io_lib:format(
        "[~s] [~p] " ++ Format ++ "~n", [Level, Pid | Args])),
    FileMsg = ["[", httpd_util:rfc1123_date(), "] ", ConsoleMsg],
    {ConsoleMsg, iolist_to_binary(FileMsg)}.

read(Bytes, Offset) ->
    LogFileName = couch_config:get("log", "file"),
    LogFileSize = filelib:file_size(LogFileName),
    MaxChunkSize = list_to_integer(
        couch_config:get("httpd", "log_max_chunk_size", "1000000")),
    case Bytes > MaxChunkSize of
    true ->
        throw({bad_request, "'bytes' cannot exceed " ++
            integer_to_list(MaxChunkSize)});
    false ->
        ok
    end,

    {ok, Fd} = file:open(LogFileName, [read]),
    Start = lists:max([LogFileSize - Bytes, 0]) + Offset,

    % TODO: truncate chopped first line
    % TODO: make streaming

    {ok, Chunk} = file:pread(Fd, Start, LogFileSize),
    ok = file:close(Fd),
    Chunk.

%%%couch_event_sup.erl
% Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
% use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
% the License at
%
%   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
%
% Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
% distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
% WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
% License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
% the License.

%% The purpose of this module is to allow event handlers to particpate in Erlang
%% supervisor trees. It provide a monitorable process that crashes if the event
%% handler fails. The process, when shutdown, deregisters the event handler.

-module(couch_event_sup).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-include("couch_db.hrl").

-export([start_link/3,start_link/4, stop/1]).
-export([init/1, terminate/2, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,code_change/3]).

%
% Instead calling the
% ok = gen_event:add_sup_handler(error_logger, my_log, Args)
%
% do this:
% {ok, LinkedPid} = couch_event_sup:start_link(error_logger, my_log, Args)
%
% The benefit is the event is now part of the process tree, and can be
% started, restarted and shutdown consistently like the rest of the server
% components.
%
% And now if the "event" crashes, the supervisor is notified and can restart
% the event handler.
%
% Use this form to named process:
% {ok, LinkedPid} = couch_event_sup:start_link({local, my_log}, error_logger, my_log, Args)
%

start_link(EventMgr, EventHandler, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(couch_event_sup, {EventMgr, EventHandler, Args}, []).

start_link(ServerName, EventMgr, EventHandler, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(ServerName, couch_event_sup, {EventMgr, EventHandler, Args}, []).

stop(Pid) ->
    gen_server:cast(Pid, stop).

init({EventMgr, EventHandler, Args}) ->
    case gen_event:add_sup_handler(EventMgr, EventHandler, Args) of
    ok ->
        {ok, {EventMgr, EventHandler}};
    {stop, Error} ->
        {stop, Error}
    end.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

handle_call(_Whatever, _From, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State}.

handle_info({gen_event_EXIT, _Handler, Reason}, State) ->
    {stop, Reason, State}.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

Comment: can you provide an example please?